# Is "A hole for peeping in" grammatical?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, idiomatic-language

Is “A hole for peeping in” grammatical?

I am wondering if the phrase is grammatical, because I found it as a definition for "peep hole" in a Hindi dictionary, but I am not sure if this is something a native person would say. Shouldn't it be "a hole for peeping through" instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both examples in the original post are grammatically correct.  The original poster's proposed definition is better than the dictionary definition.

Peepholes can be made on purpose, or can occur naturally.  All peepholes can be looked "through".

In America, many houses and apartments have peepholes in their front doors.  These peepholes have lenses, so that a person inside the door can look out through the peephole, but a person outside the door cannot see much looking in through the peephole.  With these peepholes, one can look "out", but not "in".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the definition is trying to imply.  If you want to say that a peephole is *primarily* used to surreptitiously "peep in" on someone, then yes, using "in" makes sense.

However, peepholes serve various purposes.  Many doors have one-way peepholes used for looking *out*, to check who is at the door before opening it.  If you want a more general definition then "through" would make more sense.